# Renaming multiple files in various folders to the same name in W7

Tags: windows-7, windows, rename, batch-rename

I have a bunch of directories, each one contains exactly 1 file named folder.jpg. What I would like to do is to rename all the files cover.jpg, but when I do search on *.jpg and try to rename, it renames the first file to cover.jpg and every other file becomes cover (1).jpg.

Is there a way I can rename the files without tedious folder-by-folder renaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\root\path" -Recurse -Filter "folder.jpg" | % {
  Rename-Item $_.FullName "cover.jpg"
}
```